# preventDefault() no funciona si el formulario es ejecutado con form.submit()

Tags: javascript, formularios, dom

No funciona el `event.preventDefault()` si tomo el objeto form del DOM y le ejecuto con `form.submit()` pareciese que este `form.submit()` realmente no despertara el `addEventListener('submit', () => {...})`

Este mi HTML:

```
<form method="get" id="form">
    <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
    <input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="Ingrese su Nombre" name="nombre">
    <br><br>
    <label for="apellido">Apellido</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese su Apellido" name="apellido" id="apellido">
    <br><br>
    <label for="edad">Edad</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese su Edad" name="edad" id="edad">
    <br><br>
    <button type="button" id="boton" name="boton">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

y este es mi script:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
   const form = document.getElementById("form");
   const botonSubmit = document.getElementById("boton");

   form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
      event.preventDefault();
   })

   botonSubmit.addEventListener("click", () => {
      form.submit();
   })
})
```

No deberia recargarse la pagina cuando presiono el boton enviar, sin embargo si lo hace..

Comment: es necesario tener 2 eventos?
cuando puedes agrupar todo en uno

Comment: Claro, pero la pregunta es por que el metodo `.submit()` no ejecuta el listener de `"submit"` y al parecer existe otra funcion que si lo hace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) dice que la función `submit()` es similar a activar el `submit` con un botón, pero no es exactamente igual. Paraticualmente porque la función `submit()` no activa el evento `onsubmit/submit` del formulario

> No submit event is raised. In particular, the form's event handler is
> not run

Entonces no es que `preventDefault()` no funcione, si no que sencillamente nunca entra al evento `form.addEventListener('submit', event => { //...});`n ya que no es activad

Existe la función `requestSubmit()` que es exactamente igual a activar el submit mediante botón:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const form = document.getElementById("form");
  const botonSubmit = document.getElementById("boton");

  form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Evento Submit");
  })

  botonSubmit.addEventListener("click", () => {
    form.requestSubmit();
  })
})
```

```html
<form method="get" id="form">
  <button type="button" id="boton" name="boton">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

O simplemente puedes cambiar el tipo del botón de `type=button` a `type=submit`

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const form = document.getElementById("form");

  form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Evento Submit");
  })

})
```

```html
<form method="get" id="form">
  <button type="submit" id="boton" name="boton">Enviar</button>
</form>
```